# How to calculate convolution integral?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, convolution

I know the formula for a convolution integral but how would you actually carry out one when you have two piece-wise defined functions? If you had

$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            e^{y} & \quad {-\infty}<x  < 0 \\
            e^{-y} & \quad 0<x  < {\infty} \\
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

and

$$
g(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            1 & \quad |x|  \leq 1 \\
            0 & \quad otherwise
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
?

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $f\ast g(x)=\int _\mathbb{R}f(x-y)g(y)dy=\int _{-1}^1 f(x-y)dy=\int _{-1}^xe^{y-x}dy+\int _x^1 e^{x-y}dy= \ldots $